# System command in Matlab does not work

Tags: bash, matlab

I want to execute an operating system command in Matlab. 
I have got a Latex File on my Desktop called 'test.tex'. If I type       '      `pdflatex test.tex` 
directly in the terminal, the command executes.
But if I type `system(pdflatex test.tex)` in Matlab it returns 
`/bin/bash: pdflatex: command not found.`
Why does it not work? If I type
`system(open test.tex)` this command works.

Comment: have you tried using an exclamation mark? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/run-external-commands-scripts-and-programs.html

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either

Comment: I'm using a Mac btw

Comment: In Terminal, run `type pdflatex` and it will tell you the full command it uses. Use that in your `system()` command.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: Thanks for the answer. This also works and seems to be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this line to startup.m:

```
setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':/directory/of/pdflatex/']);
```

For more details, check out the following link: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/850-matlab-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. I had to add the following to the startup.m file

```
setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin']);
setenv('PATH', [getenv('PATH') ':insert place where your file is stored']);
```